# Running and obtaining results of a python program in C

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, system-calls

The python script contains lots of libraries imported

My C code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <python2.7/Python.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    FILE* file;

    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();    
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);

    file = fopen("analyze.py","r");

    PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "analyze.py");
    Py_Finalize();                      

    return;
}
```

Is there any other way that I can use so that even if any modification in arguments or number of python scripts I call inside c program increases the same code can be used with little changes?

Can I use system call and use the result obtained from it?

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the code formatting.

Comment: Try looking at your own post for a few seconds and you should be able to tell... oh ffs I'll fix it for you.

Comment: 1) paste your code into the post 2) while it is marked, click on the code formatting icon `{}`. This will give the code correct syntax coloring and change font to Courier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this to call the python file from the C program:

`char command[50] = "python full_path_name\\file_name.py";`

`system(command);`

This piece of code worked for me...

I didn't use `# include < python2.7/Python.h>`

You can write the results from the python file to any text file and then use the results stored in the text file to do whatever you want to do...

You can also have a look at this post for further help:

[Calling python script from C++ and using its output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962430/calling-python-script-from-c-and-using-its-output?rq=1)

Comment: Try using `#!usr/bin/python` at the beginning of the python script

Comment: I didn't use version... I was using python 2.7... and this worked for me

Comment: I guess you can use `argparse` in your python script...

And in the C code you can edit the `command` string like this: 



`char command[100] = 'python full_path_name\\file_name.py arg1 arg2 ..argn'`

Comment: You can also use `import sys`
in your python script
and use `sys.argv[i]` to access the corresponding arguments where `i` is the position of the argument in the command line

Comment: You can have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125828/capturing-stdout-from-a-system-command-optimally?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156620/c-programming-handling-stdout-and-stdin-using-pipes?rq=1

Comment: I saw your other posts.. :| .... you can just concatenate strings to include the arguments in `command` in which case you have to take the length of the buffer taking into consideration the argument lengths in string format...

I hope you are getting me?? I am a beginner as well... -__-

Answer (score 1):

One useful way is calling a python function within c, which is that you need instead of execute whole script.

As described in 
[>> here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286448/calling-a-python-method-from-c-c-and-extracting-its-return-value)